# Restricting paste event not working in safari

Tags: angular, safari, paste

Restricting paste event not working in safari

below code is working in chrome but not safari

```
@HostListener('paste', ['$event']) blockPaste(event: KeyboardEvent) 
{
    this.validateFields(event);
}


validateFields(event) {
   setTimeout(() => {
         let numberRegEx = /^[0-9]+$/;
                if (!numberRegEx.test(this.el.nativeElement.value)) {
                      this.el.nativeElement.value = '';
                                event.preventDefault();
                 }
     }, 0);
 }
```

demo- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-numbers-only-directive-agqq9t?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts